# How can I superimpose gradient field on a 2D heatmap generated from a csv file in python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv

I have a heatmap generated from a csv file as below: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3GP6.png)

Now I need to superimpose a gradient field on this. I tried with numpy.gradient, but it is not working perfectly. Here is the python code I tried.

```
import csv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns



data_path = 'sed2.csv' # this is a two dimensional array with 51 row and 47 columns
with open(data_path, 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    # get header from first row
    headers = next(reader)
    # get all the rows as a list
    data = list(reader)
    # transform data into numpy array
    data = np.array(data).astype(float)

#print(headers)
#print(data.shape)
#print(data[:,1:47])
[gx,gy]=np.gradient(np.array(data[:,1:47], dtype=float)) # here I calculated the gradient from a 51x47 matrix 


plt.rcParams['font.size'] = 30
df=pd.read_csv('n_vs_c_sed.csv') # this reads file with heading: n c sed

df_pivot=df.pivot('c', 'n', 'sed')
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
sns.heatmap(df_pivot, cmap='RdGy',  annot=False,  square=True, cbar=True, xticklabels=15, yticklabels=10)
ax.set_yticklabels(ax.get_yticklabels(), rotation=0)

for _, spine in ax.spines.items():
    spine.set_visible(True)
    spine.set_linewidth(1.0)
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
ax.set_aspect(aspect=.9)
plt.savefig('SED.png', dpi = 300, transparent = True, bbox_inches = 'tight', pad_inches = 0)
#plt.contour(df_pivot, 15, colors='black')
n = np.linspace(5,50,46)
c= np.linspace(0,.5,20)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(n,c)
plt.quiver(X,Y,gy,gx,width=.003,linewidth=1)
plt.show()
```

The result I got from this is given [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6rUE.png), that is not expected. However, if I run only the code for quiver plot as follows:

```
import csv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
data_path = 'sed2.csv'
with open(data_path, 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    # get header from first row
    headers = next(reader)
    # get all the rows as a list
    data = list(reader)
    # transform data into numpy array
    data = np.array(data).astype(float)



   #print(headers)
#print(data.shape)
#print(data[:,1:47])
[gx,gy]=np.gradient(np.array(data[:,1:47], dtype=float))
dx = np.linspace(5,50,46)
dy= np.linspace(0,.5,20)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(dx,dy)
#u,v=np.meshgrid(gx,gy)
plt.quiver(X,Y,gy,gx,width=.002,linewidth=0.5)
plt.show()
```

It gives the plot [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXwHJ.png).
Any kind of suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It's not working` does not tell us enough!  Since we can't run your code, you need to provide more details.  Better yet prove a [mcve]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. This time I have included more description of the problem.